# html how to create frames

Tags: html, ajax, frames, frameset

I would like to create an html frameset like the picture below.

can anyone point me in an helpful direction as I'm not sure how to create this?

Should I use frameset or something else like AJAX?

```
------------------------------------------
|                                        |
|                                        |
|----------------------------------------|
|     |                                  |
|     |                                  |
|     |                                  |
|     |                                  |
|     |                                  |
|     |                                  |
|     |                                  |
|     |                                  |
|     |                                  |
------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Hey guys, someone has been sent from the early nineties!

Comment: You could ask this question in http://doctype.com

Comment: "guys, the cake is a lie!" http://xkcd.com/606/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use frames and framesets as they are [deprecated in HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-html5-diff-20090423/#absent-elements). You don't need Ajax, since layout has nothing to do with asynchronous updates. Instead, use a CSS layout [like one of these examples](http://layouts.ironmyers.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You can learn about frames and framesets from the [excellent tutorials available](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_frameset.asp) from the w3schools. However, as a word of advice, AJAX is not particularly involved in the management of framesets in any special or unique way. Besides, you can achieve the desired layout using the CSS box model just fine! Plenty of examples on the web. Check out the stuff at [OSWD](http://www.oswd.org/), [CSS Zen Garden](http://www.csszengarden.com/) and plenty of others around the web. CSS is your friend and it looks (usually) much better than frameset.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/frames.html) you have some doc about frames, but are you sure you want to do that? I won't explain here why it's bad but it really is, for many reasons.

Could you edit your question to explain more precisely what you are trying to achieve? Like this we'll may be able to tell you what's your best choice, because may be you don't even need AJAX.

Comment: Hi
I'm trying to create a menu bar (the top frame), a side bar and then the main frame I would like to pass in a variable to change its contents (Its a php page) - A bit like this: http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=test&btnG=Google+Search&meta=&aq=f&oq=

Comment: The two other answer are good for what you want. And since you have php, consider using `include` to "simulate" your frame.

Comment: @Adam: If you look at the source for the example Google page you give there, you'll see that there aren't any frames at all.  You can achieve the look and feel you want without using frames.